# Trigger validation for empty field

Tags: parsley.js

I have 3 phone fields and at least one of them must be filled. The problem is that parsley validation does not work when field is empty, so it does not show any error. How can I trigger validation even when field is empty?

Here is HTML:

```
<form parsley-validate id="demo-form">
Phone1 <input type="text" name="phone1" id="phone1" /><br>
Phone2 <input type="text" name="phone2" id="phone2" /><br>
Phone3 <input type="text" name="phone3" id="phone3" parsley-phones /><br>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="$('#demo-form').parsley('validate');">
</form>
```

And here is Javascript:

```
(function ($) {
    window.ParsleyConfig = $.extend( true, {}, window.ParsleyConfig, {
        validators: {
            phones: function () {
                return {
                    validate: function(val) {
                        if($("#phone1").val()=='' && $("#phone2").val()=='' && $("#phone3").val()=='')
                            return false;
                        else
                            return true;
                    }
                    , priority: 100
                }
            }
        }
        , messages: {
                phones: "At least one phone number is required."
        }
    });
}(window.jQuery || window.Zepto));
```

Comment: Do you need to specify `validateIfUnchanged: true`?

Comment: I added "validateIfUnchanged: true" and also added hidden input field like this:

    <input type="text" name="dummy_phone" value="1" style="display:none" parsley-phones>

It does not look elegant, but at least it works...

Comment: I made a fiddle with your code, but found that parsley skips the custom field validation if the field is empty. I might mention this limitation to the developer.

Comment: It works OK for me as long as this dummy field has value="1" or any value in it. If it is empty - yea, parsley skips the validation.

Answer (score 5):

You probably just have to add a special attribute `data-parsley-validate-if-empty` to the input.

Here is the relevant part of parsley.js source code:

```
// An empty optional field does not need validation
needsValidation: function needsValidation(value) {
  if ('undefined' === typeof value) value = this.getValue();

  // If a field is empty and not required, it is valid
  // Except if `data-parsley-validate-if-empty` explicitely added, useful for some custom validators
  if (!value.length && !this._isRequired() && 'undefined' === typeof this.options.validateIfEmpty) return false;

  return true;
},
```

And documentation:
http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-usage-field
Quote:

> A field is by default not validated if it is not required and empty.
>   By adding data-parsley-validate-if-empty, validation will be done even
>   if field is empty. Useful if you need some custom validators that
>   check something particular when a field is empty.

Comment: data-parsley-validate-if-empty is available from parsley v2 and will work fine. My solution above is for someone who is still using v1.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the attribute, "required" to each input that you want to prevent from being submitted empty. For example:

```
 <input type="text" name="phone1" id="phone1" required />
```

Comment: But which means phone1 is always required. In my case, only phone1, 2 or 3 are required.

Comment: This helped with simple validation of empty fields. Not the OP but mine was much simpler. Reading above this probably also will work but I didn't test it. Quick and dirty above worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the event before validation:

```
$.listen('parsley:field:validate', function(){
    # your validation here
})
```

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-events-usage